# Why does the tonearm cable from my turntable pick up noise?

Tags: noise, noise-reduction, hum

I have recently pick up an old turntable (my detailed setup goes below) and facing the background noise issue. I think it is something being picked up by my tonearm cable because when I move it or touch it - the sound changes. Also I found out that when I unplug tonearm cable from the preamp, the noise reduces and disappears completely when second channel is disconnected.

Here is what I hear from the loudspeakers (volume really cranked up - you can't hear normal record at such volume). Recorded using my phone put close to the speaker (ogg file):

https://yadi.sk/d/FFCqbmCP3SqL7w

My setup goes as follows: 
Mains 230V 50Hz
Turntable - Denon DP-47F, 100V japanese version, plugged through transformer, not connected to mains earth
Cartridge is Goldring E3 (MM)
Preamp - Cambridge audio Duo, connected to mains via earthed cable
Tonearm cable - noname, how well is shielded is unknown. L/R channel + and - as well as ground is soldered to PCB under tonearm inside the turntable.
Amplifier - I use receiver Yamaha RX-V467, not earthed to mains.

My best idea as for now is to use some braided copper sleeve like this:  [https://www.amazon.com/Tinned-Copper-Braided-Sleeving-Diameter/dp/B01MEG9V2R/ref=sr_1_17?keywords=tonearm%2Bcable&qid=1571934888&sr=8-17&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MEG9V2R)

Put L/R cables inside this and replace the ground turntable cable with it - solder it to the ground connection inside the turntable and also connect it to ground terminal on the preamp.

If anyone can give some advice on that, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: HiFi is off-topic here, but broadly, you have too many things un-earthed. Strap them all together & earth through a single plug-board on a properly earthed socket. If you have a Japanese transformer, that may confound that, as most of them aren't earthed at all, unless they're lab versions with a separate earth strap.

Comment: @Tetsujin I cannot earth receiver and turntable as there is no earth terminal on them :(

Comment: [horribly long google link] [Self-drilling screw](https://www.google.com/search?q=self-drilling+screw&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimo-vcxLXlAhUTilwKHckZD9kQ_AUIESgB&biw=1204&bih=1291) through the back-plate [check what's behind it, of course]. Done. Wire them all together that way if there's nothing else.

Comment: @Tetsujin you mean earthing the chassis I guess. Won't work for the turntable at its chassis is wood (or MDF perhaps), non-conductive either way.

Comment: Everything has an earth plane somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by putting wires inside a metal sleeve and connecting it to the ground, so it act like Faraday cage.